# Customized (de)serializing of XmlDocument member

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have following class:

```
[XmlRoot("testclass")]
public class TestClass
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("items")]
    public XmlDocument Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now the class is initialized with following data:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(@"
      <items>
        <item>
          <name>item1</name>
          <value>value1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <name>item2</name>
          <value>value2</value>
        </item>
       </items>
         ");

TestClass tc = new TestClass() {
    Name = "testclass",
    Value = "testclassvalue",
    Items = xml
};
```

When I serialize (.NET XmlSerializer) this classI get following xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<testclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <name>testclass</name>
    <value>testclassvalue</value>
    <items>
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>item1</name>
                <value>value1</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>item2</name>
                <value>value2</value>
            </item>
        </items>
    </items>
</testclass>
```

What would be the best way to get xmlserializer to output  node like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<testclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <name>testclass</name>
    <value>testclassvalue</value>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>item1</name>
            <value>value1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>item2</name>
            <value>value2</value>
        </item>
    </items>
</testclass>
```

Also what would the best way to serialize this xml back to my class? So that xmlelement starting with  node would be deserialized back into my ItemsXml member.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
[XmlElement("items")]
public XmlDocument Items { get; set; }
```

To just:

```
// [XmlArray("items")] <--- you can add this to get a lowercase "items"
// [XmlArrayItem("item")] <--- and this to name the actual item
public XmlDocument Items { get; set; }
```

So without the `[XmlElement("items")]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not help. 

Removing XmlElement("items") just changes first element to uppercase <Items>. XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute can only be specified to array types (arrays and collections) - exception is thrown: 
For non-array types, you may use the following attributes: XmlAttribute, XmlText, XmlElement, or XmlAnyElement.

Comment: sorry... wasn't concentrating --- only noticed now that you are using XmlDocument as the type.  Any reason why you can't use class called Item with name and value properties?

Comment: I provided items xml as a simple example (perhaps too simple :)). In real application this items xml has much more complicated structure. So this simple class would not do.